# Can't pass file path to a Batch file

Tags: batch-file

I'm new to programming so apologies in advance if this is really simple.

I'm using PA File Sight to monitor a folder for open files. When a file is opened it starts a program (batch file in this case) and passes the entire file path to the variable: $Item(1)$

The batch file looks like this at the moment:

```
set FILE_PATH="$Item(1)$"
echo.>%FILE_PATH%_IS_OPEN
```

I'm trying to get the batch file to create a new file with IS_OPEN on the end of it so that users know that a file "is open"

Running the batch file creates the following in it's folder:

```
$Item(1)$_IS_OPEN
```

So it's not storing the path for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest you try

```
set FILE_PATH="%~1"
echo. "%FILE_PATH%_IS_OPEN"
echo.>"%FILE_PATH%_IS_OPEN"
PAUSE
```

This should set `FILE_PATH` to the first parameter that the batch file sees - the `~` removes any enclosing quotes

The next line echoes the result to the console and may be removed if the test proves successful.

The third line encloses the proposed filename in quotes to allow the use of spaces in the filename generated.

The PAUSE holds the CMD window open until you press `ENTER` to allow you to see the results. It too can be removed if your results are as expected.

---

modified to replace the first 2 characters of the NAME portion with "AA"

```
set FILE_PATH="%~1"
FOR /f "delims=" %%i IN ("%file_path%") DO (SET dpi=%%~dpi&SET ni=%%~ni&SET xi=%%~xi)
SET file_path=%dpi%AA%ni:~2%%xi%
echo. "%FILE_PATH%_IS_OPEN"
echo.>"%FILE_PATH%_IS_OPEN"
PAUSE
```

This assumes that it's the first 2 characters that need to be replaced. It works by assuming that the literal-string in the variable `file_path` is a filename whic, miracle of miracles, it is. `dpi` is then set to the drive and path, `ni` to the name and `xi` to the extension. then the full name is reconstructed, substituting `AA` for the first 2 characters of the name (`dpi` (the path) + AA + `ni:2` (the name from the second character to the end) + `xi` (the extension))

Comment: Thanks will try this afternoon and let you know

Comment: Nice one. It does make more sense that the program passes the filename in the startup parameters.

Comment: That is working this morning !
(I tried it last night but it didn't work)

Comment: Morning @Peter,  

Can I please ask a follow up question ?  

In the case of a Word file %FILE_PATH% contains a ~$ like so:  

c:\documents and settings\admin\my documents\~$etter1.docx  

Is it possible to replace the ~$ with AA for example ?
  
Thanks again

Comment: Good morning @Peter,

rats - can't get it to work. Doesn't produce anything in the folder where the Word file is opened.
I put the batch file in c:\batch. When I double click the batch file it produces a file called AA~2%xi_IS_OPEN in c:\batch if that is any help
thanks

Comment: I've made a small edit - the `FOR` becomes `for /f "delims="` - I was not including the enclosing quotes on `file_path` in my testing, however the only way I could provoke `AA~2%xi_` to appear was by adding a `%` after the `:` in the second `set file_path=` instruction... If any further problem, please report the values of `dpi`, `ni` and `xi` as well. (easily done with SET dpi/SET ni/SET xi on separate lines...

Comment: @Peter - We can declare this little project solved, many thanks to you.
How does one award points in Stack Overflow?
Do I need to close the question ?
thank again,
Brett

Comment: I haven't a clue actually, as I've never asked a question. SHould be an "Accept answer" button somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

`$Item(1)$` seems like a constant string. If `$Item(1)$` is the name of an actual environment variable, your first line should be

```
set FILE_PATH="%$Item(1)$%"
```

Although that seems quite an odd name for a variable.

Comment: The program also sends a pop up message and $Item(1)$ is expanded into  a path. I Am using XP if that makes any difference ?

Comment: Would this be easier to do in VBScript ? The program can trigger a VBScript.

thanks again